# To evaluate the given determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

**Question:** Evaluate the determinant 
$\left|
\begin{array}{cc} b^2c^2 & bc & b+c \\ 
c^2a^2 & ca & c+a \\ 
a^2b^2 & ab & a+b \\ 
\end{array}
\right|$

**My answer:**

$\left|
\begin{array}{cc} b^2c^2 & bc & b+c \\ 
c^2a^2 & ca & c+a \\ 
a^2b^2 & ab & a+b \\ 
\end{array}
\right|= \left|
\begin{array}{cc} b^2c^2 & bc & c \\ 
c^2a^2 & ca & a \\ 
a^2b^2 & ab & b \\ 
\end{array}
\right| + \left|
\begin{array}{cc} b^2c^2 & bc & b \\ 
c^2a^2 & ca & c \\ 
a^2b^2 & ab & a \\ 
\end{array}
\right|= abc \left|
 \begin{array}{cc} bc^2 & c & 1 \\ 
ca^2 & a & 1 \\ 
ab^2 & b & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right| +abc \left|
\begin{array}{cc} b^2c & b & 1 \\ 
c^2a & c & 1 \\ 
a^2b & a & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right|$

how do I proceed from here?

Comment: I think in general, $|A + B| \neq |A| + |B|$.

Comment: It is multilinear in the columns...

Answer (score 3):

This is probably the shortest way:-
$$
\begin{align}
\begin{vmatrix} b^2c^2 & bc & b+c \\\ 
c^2a^2 & ca & c+a \\\ 
a^2b^2 & ab & a+b 
\end{vmatrix}
 &=a^3b^3c^3\begin{vmatrix}a^{-1} &1 & b^{-1}+c^{-1}\\\ b^{-1} &1&a^{-1}+c^{-1}\\\ c^{-1} &1& a^{-1}+b^{-1}\end{vmatrix}\\
&=(abc)^3\left(\frac 1a+\frac 1b+\frac 1c\right)\begin{vmatrix}
a^{-1}&1&1\\\ b^{-1}&1&1\\\ c^{-1} &1 &1
\end{vmatrix}
\\
&=0
\end{align}
$$
What I did was to first take out $bc$ , $ca$ and $ab$ common from the rows individually. Then I took out $abc$ from the first column.

Comment: That's an handsome answer, yet, how do you have $a^3b^3c^3$?

Comment: @Marine1 I'll edit in some more steps to add detail.

Comment: When either a,b, or c is 0, the matrix is singular as well.... Otherwise you can't divide by a,b,c. W.l.o.g. c is 0, then rows 1 and 2 are linear dependent (0,0,b) and (0,0,a).

Answer (score 2):

$F=\left|
\begin{array}{cc} b^2c^2 & bc & b+c \\ 
c^2a^2 & ca & c+a \\ 
a^2b^2 & ab & a+b \\ 
\end{array}
\right|$

$=\dfrac1{abc}\left|
\begin{array}{cc} ab^2c^2 & abc & a(b+c) \\ 
c^2a^2b & bca & b(c+a) \\ 
a^2b^2c & abc & c(a+b) \\ 
\end{array}
\right|$

$=\left|
\begin{array}{cc} ab^2c^2 &1& a(b+c) \\ 
c^2a^2b &1& b(c+a) \\ 
a^2b^2c &1& c(a+b) \\ 
\end{array}
\right|$

$R_3'=R_3-R_1,R_2'=R_2-R_1$

$F=\left|
\begin{array}{cc} ab^2c^2 &1& a(b+c) \\ 
abc^2(a-b) &0& -a(a-b) \\ 
-ab^2c(c-a) &0& b(c-a) \\ 
\end{array}
\right|$

$=(a-b)(c-a)\left|
\begin{array}{cc} ab^2c^2 &1& a(b+c) \\ 
abc^2 &0& -a \\ 
-ab^2c &0& b \\ 
\end{array}
\right|$

$=(a-b)(c-a)(-1)^{1+2}\cdot\left|
\begin{array}{cc} abc^2 & -a \\ 
-ab^2c & b \\ 
\end{array}
\right|$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Your given matrix is : $\left|
\begin{array}{cc} b^2c^2 & bc & b+c \\ 
c^2a^2 & ca & c+a \\ 
a^2b^2 & ab & a+b \\ 
\end{array}
\right|$

[Determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) of the given matrix is :

$\implies b^2c^2[ca^2 + abc - abc + a^2b] - bc[a^3c^2 + a^2bc^2 - a^2b^2c - a^3b^2] + (b+c)[a^3bc^2 - a^3b^2c]$

$\implies b^2c^2[ca^2  + a^2b] - bc[a^3c^2 + a^2bc^2 - a^2b^2c - a^3b^2] + (b+c)[a^3bc^2 - a^3b^2c]$

$\implies a^2b^2c^3 - a^2b^3c^2 - a^3bc^3 - a^2b^2c^3 + a^2b^3c^2 + a^3b^3c + a^3b^2c^2 - a^3b^3c + a^3bc^3 - a^3b^2c^2$

$\implies a^2b^2c^3 - a^2b^2c^3 - a^2b^3c^2 + a^2b^3c^2 - a^3bc^3 + a^3bc^3  + a^3b^3c - a^3b^3c + a^3b^2c^2  - a^3b^2c^2$

$\implies 0$

Therefore, given matrix is singular.